# Can we say that: $|g|<M\text{ a.e} $

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and 
$$
\mathcal{L}^1=\left\{f:E\to \mathbb{R}: \int_{E}{|f(t)|d\mu(t)}<\infty\right\}
$$
Let $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^1$, such that:
$$
\forall t\in E :|f_n(t)|\leq M\qquad (1)
$$
$$
\exists g\in\mathcal{L}^1, \text{such that } f_n\underset{n}{\to}g\text{ weakly in }\mathcal{L}^1\qquad (2)
$$
Can we say that:
$$
|g|<M\text{ a.e}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can say that. For any set $E$ with $\mu (E)>0$ we have $\int_E gd\mu=\int gI_E d\mu =\lim \int fI_E d\mu $since $I_E \in L^{\infty}$. This gives $|\int_E gd\mu|  \leq M \mu (E)$. Since this is true for all $E$ with  $\mu (E)>0$ it follows that $|g| \leq M$ a.e.. [ To see this you can use the choices $E=\{x: g(x) >M\}$ and $E=\{x: g (x) <-M\}$].